# Separate $or queries in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongomapper

I am having an issue crafting a good query for what I need. I need two separate OR clauses for my query. to clarify, I'll give an example:

```
{ $or : [ { key1 : valueA }, { key2 : valueB } ], $or: [{ key3 : valueC }, 
    { key4 : valueD }]}
```

This query just does an OR operation on all of the keys and values. What I need is two separate OR queries. So what I need is (not in code):

```
(key1 : valueA OR key2 : valueB) and (key3 : valueC OR key4 : valueD)
```

Does anyone have an efficient and Mongo-ish way to complete such query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo does have $and capability.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24and

Comment: Yeah. Thank you. I actually thought of that while I was writing this. Is that the most efficient way to do this? I just worry about nesting AND and OR.

Comment: It should be fine. I've done it before with good results. I have seen nothing to the contrary in my general searches.